# jcifs/smb/NtlmPasswordAuthentication error while connecting to SQL Server with JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL database with `JDBC` and getting the below error :

```
jcifs/smb/NtlmPasswordAuthentication
```

here is my connection string :

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:/< host_name>/< db_name>;instance=< instance_name>;namedPipe=true
```

tried this one too :

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:/< host_name.domain_name>/< db_name>;instance=< instance_name>;namedPipe=true
```

Got same error every time. Any particular reason why I might be getting this error.

I am using the `JDDS(net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)` driver and the instance is configured to run on dynamic ports.

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

```
jdbc:sqlserver:// (Required) is known as the sub-protocol and is constant.

serverName (Optional) is the address of the server to connect to. This could be a DNS or IP address, or it could be localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the local computer. If not specified in the connection URL, the server name must be specified in the properties collection.

instanceName (Optional) is the instance to connect to on serverName. If not specified, a connection to the default instance is made.

portNumber (Optional) is the port to connect to on serverName. The default is 1433. If you are using the default, you do not have to specify the port, nor its preceding ':', in the URL.
```

Connect to the default database on the local computer by using a user name and password:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;
```

To use a port number, do the following (named & multiple instances)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;<more properties as required>;
```

To use a JDBC URL property, do the following (named & multiple instances)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=instance1;integratedSecurity=true;<more properties as required>;
```

Connect to the default database on the local computer by using integrated authentication:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Connect to a named database on a remote server:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Connect on the default port to the remote server:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Connect by specifying a customized application name:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;applicationName=MyApp;
```

To use a port number, do the following:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;<more properties as required>;
```

To use a JDBC URL property, do the following:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=instance1;integratedSecurity=true;<more properties as required>;
```

To use the serverName property (IPV6)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=3ffe:8311:eeee:f70f:0:5eae:10.203.31.9\\instance1;integratedSecurity=true;
```

To use the properties collection (IPV6)

```
Properties pro = new Properties();

pro.setProperty("serverName", "serverName=3ffe:8311:eeee:f70f:0:5eae:10.203.31.9\\instance1");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://;integratedSecurity=true;", pro);
```

Comment: Why do you specify `localhost` (e.g. in "connect to a named database on a remote server") if it is a database on a remote host?